# STM32F4xx phase shift of carrier wave (timers)

Tags: timer, stm32, pwm

I just want to generate PWM signals for single phase cascade H bridge inverter.
Theortically speaking, I need to shift carrier wave (triangular or sawtooth) in order to get sinusoidal PWM (see picture). I don't know how to obtain these shifted waves with stm32 (also I need complementary output so using TIM1 is obvious choice).

My idea is to use TIM1 and check in interrupt actual value of TIM1 and start another timer, but STM32F11 has only one timer with complementary output (TIM1).

Thx for any help

Picture is from "Pulse Width Modulation for Power Converters - principles and practice"
[image]